# may i know how to write a SQL query to check if the superset of value exists in the same column

Tags: sql, oracle

i am trying to check if a superset of value exists in the same column, if exists select only the superset row.
Here is my data.
[Here is the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TDQx.png)

| ID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | abc |
| 2 | abcd |
| 3 | abcde |
| 4 | xyz |
| 5 | lmn |
| 6 | lmno |

ID 3 is the superset of 1 and 2, ID 4 doesn't have any superset and ID 6 is the superset of 5. so i am expecting ID 3,4 and 6 in the result set.

Appreciate any inputs on this.
Note: i am using Oracle as my DB.

Following is the expected result:

[Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGKnP.png)

| ID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | abcde |
| 4 | xyz |
| 6 | lmno |

Comment: Please describe in general words how you identify some value as a superset. Then it would be possible to translate that conditions into SQL conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with data(ID, Value) as (
    select 1, 'abc' from dual union all
    select 2, 'abcd' from dual union all
    select 3, 'abcde' from dual union all
    select 4, 'xyz' from dual union all
    select 5, 'lmn' from dual union all
    select 6, 'lmno' from dual -- union all
)
select * from data d1
where not exists(select 1 from data d2 where d1.id <> d2.id and substr(d2.value, 1, length(d1.value)) = d1.value)
;


6   lmno
4   xyz
3   abcde
```